# Adding keyboard hide button in accessory bar in Ionic

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using the ionic framework to create my app and I use a lot of forms with modals. In order to move between fields a user normally taps on the space where there isn't any image however this can lead to unexpected behaviour.

I would like a button to hide the keyboard exactly like the image below.

[image: iOS keyboard accessory bar]

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cordova, you can first install this plugin

```
cordova plugin add com.ionic.keyboard
```

Then, in your callback, initiate

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.close();
```

Some information regarding attaching an element above the keyboard.

> keyboard-attach is an attribute directive which will cause an element
>   to float above the keyboard when the keyboard shows. Currently only
>   supports the ion-footer-bar directive.

On iOS, if there is an input in your footer, you will need to set

```
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true)
```

**The Usage**

```
<ion-footer-bar align-title="left" keyboard-attach class="bar-assertive">
    <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

Comment: I'm using ionic's keyboard. And how would I position a button in this area to attach a function to it?

Comment: Most users will probably click on the word 'Done' since that is what they are normally used to.  Is this not what you are not looking for?

Comment: This doesn't work how I asked in my op. The footer doesn't sit right on top of the keyboard it goes up above it, yes, but it doesn't give the desired result!